# How to process websocket messages concurrently in Python with asyncio?

Tags: python, flask, websocket, async-await, socket.io

I have the following simple implementation of a websockets program (it's actually in Flask, but I don't believe it's relevant for this case):

```py
import asyncio
import websockets

from flask_socketio import SocketIO

socketio = SocketIO(app)

async def processMessageText(data):
    # First processing
    await asyncio.sleep(30)

async def processMessageResult(data):
    # Second processing
    await asyncio.sleep(5)

async def main():
    async with websockets.connect("wss://websocket.example/ws") as websocket:
        await websocket.send('{"some":"data"}')
        async for m in websocket:
            message = json.loads(m)
            socketio.emit('echo_data', message, json=True)

            if message['flag']:
                # Further processing
                result = await processMessageText(message)
                final_data = await processMessageResult(result)
                socketio.emit('processed_data', final_data, json=True)

asyncio.run(main())
```

The thing is, I keep receiving multiple messages from the websocket connection every second. I capture them all without a problem. However, on those messages that need further processing where the `message['flag']` is present, this code seems to behave synchronously.

On both lines `result = await processMessageText(message)` and `final_data = await processMessageResult(result)`, I was expecting `asyncio` to let the CPU go to the next websocket message, while processing the current message in the background (which will take aprox 30 + 5 seconds).

Essentially I wanted the program to `socketio.emit('echo_data')` the messages that do not require further processing **as soon as possible**, and then to `socketio.emit('processed_data')` whenever the processing has been finished for each message that needed further processing.

For a websocket connection with the following messages received:

```
message_to_echo_1
message_to_echo_2
message_to_process_3
message_to_echo_4
message_to_echo_5
message_to_echo_6
message_to_process_7
message_to_process_8
message_to_echo_9
message_to_echo_10
message_to_process_11
message_to_echo_12
```

On the frontend I was expecting to receive, something like this as fast as possible:

```
echo_data_1
echo_data_2
echo_data_3
echo_data_4
echo_data_5
echo_data_6
echo_data_7
echo_data_8
echo_data_9
echo_data_10
echo_data_11
echo_data_12
processed_data_3
processed_data_7
processed_data_8
processed_data_11
```

At the moment I'm receiving this (each websocket message is processed until the end, whether it needs further processing or not):

```
echo_data_1
echo_data_2
echo_data_3
processed_data_3
echo_data_4
echo_data_5
echo_data_6
echo_data_7
processed_data_7
echo_data_8
processed_data_8
echo_data_9
echo_data_10
echo_data_11
processed_data_11
echo_data_12
```

Can anyone help me achieve parallelism on this?

**EDIT 1**
Javascript:

```js
var socket = io();

socket.on('echo_data', (data) => {
    console.log(data);
});
socket.on('processed_data', (data) => {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: Can you also update your code with the javascript you have?

Comment: At the moment I'm just printing the output into the console for debugging